# How to convert a list of nested list from a json file into a dataframe in R?

Tags: python, r, json, dataframe, data-conversion

I have a json file which has nested elements.

```
List of 2
 $ :List of 5
  ..$ sname          : chr "AS323"
  ..$ sDescription   : chr "FILTER"
  ..$ sPrice         : chr "0.00"
  ..$ TaxExemptStatus: chr "N"
  ..$ components     :List of 1
  .. ..$ scomponent:List of 1
  .. .. ..$ :List of 15
  .. .. .. ..$ id               : chr "25161877"
  .. .. .. ..$ mfg              : chr "LR"
  .. .. .. ..$ RequestedQuantity: int 1
  .. .. .. ..$ qh               : int 5
  .. .. .. ..$ List             : chr "8.00"
  .. .. .. ..$ Trade            : chr "5.41"
  .. .. .. ..$ Cost             : chr "3.87"
  .. .. .. ..$ Company          : chr "jbl"
  .. .. .. ..$ Price            : chr "0"
  .. .. .. ..$ desc             : chr "FILTER "
  .. .. .. ..$ sgh              : chr "100"
  .. .. .. ..$ myLocation       : chr "56"
  .. .. .. ..$ QuantityAvailable: int 5
  .. .. .. ..$ QuantityInProcess: int 0
  .. .. .. ..$ sl               : NULL
 $ :List of 5
  ..$ sname          : chr "P012"
  ..$ sDescription   : chr "P012"
  ..$ sPrice         : chr "0.00"
  ..$ TaxExemptStatus: chr "N"
  ..$ components     :List of 1
  .. ..$ scomponent:List of 2
  .. .. ..$ :List of 15
  .. .. .. ..$ id               : chr "19249"
  .. .. .. ..$ mfg              : chr "LX"
  .. .. .. ..$ RequestedQuantity: int 1
  .. .. .. ..$ qh               : int 0
  .. .. .. ..$ List             : chr "10.40"
  .. .. .. ..$ Trade            : chr "7.28"
  .. .. .. ..$ Cost             : chr "5.20"
  .. .. .. ..$ Company          : chr "jbl"
  .. .. .. ..$ Price            : chr "0"
  .. .. .. ..$ desc             : chr "SL-N"
  .. .. .. ..$ sgh              : chr "100"
  .. .. .. ..$ myLocation       : chr "NY"
  .. .. .. ..$ QuantityAvailable: int 0
  .. .. .. ..$ QuantityInProcess: int 0
  .. .. .. ..$ sl               : NULL
  .. .. ..$ :List of 15
  .. .. .. ..$ id               : chr "192900"
  .. .. .. ..$ mfg              : chr "LX"
  .. .. .. ..$ RequestedQuantity: int 6
  .. .. .. ..$ qh               : int 1341
  .. .. .. ..$ List             : chr "4.25"
  .. .. .. ..$ Trade            : chr "5.13"
  .. .. .. ..$ Cost             : chr "3.50"
  .. .. .. ..$ Company          : chr "jbl"
  .. .. .. ..$ Price            : chr "0"
  .. .. .. ..$ desc             : chr "N"
  .. .. .. ..$ sgh              : chr "100"
  .. .. .. ..$ myLocation       : chr "78"
  .. .. .. ..$ QuantityAvailable: int 1341
  .. .. .. ..$ QuantityInProcess: int 0
  .. .. .. ..$ sl               : NULL
```

I want to convert this list into observations.The above sample has 3 records and 19 variables. I have tried unnest and rbind but couldn't get the required output. Can anyone provide any similar approaches to flatten such files. I am expecting for list in the components in the original file. I am looking for a generic solution which can be used on all kind of nested lists.

Comment: Did you type 3 when you meant 2?

Comment: no its actually 3.. as the second list is list of 2
sname
AS323
P012
P012